# How to write an if else in script tag in azure yaml?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
    - script: |
            sfdx force:org:clone -t sandbox SandboxName=${{ parameters.sandboxName }} SourceSandboxName=TrainingENV description="Training Environment Clone" -u prod | tee clone_result
            if grep -q "timed out" clone_result; \
              then \
                exit 0 \
            fi
      displayName: Cloning TrainingENV into ${{ parameters.sandboxName }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslashes are your problem.

```bash
if grep -q "timed out" clone_result; then
  exit 0
fi
```

works just fine. `fi` in particular needs to be a separate command.

Comment: `fi` in particular needs to be a separate command. Sorry still confuse what does this mean?

Comment: @Mr.Nobody Escaping the newlines will be interpreted as if `then exit 0 fi` was written as a single line, forming a single command. This makes `fi` an argument. But you want to execute the *builtin* `fi`, not give the *text* `fi` as argument.